# Issues with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to build a simple app in Xcode however I'm getting this error saying build failed

:0: error: PCH was compiled with module cache path '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/5JW54F8EE7JD', but the path is currently '/Users/Neil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/5JW54F8EE7JD'
:0: error: missing required module 'SwiftShims'

what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Got the answer for this issue, https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/64345

Comment: the pathes look different where it expects to find it and where it actually resides! 
https://www.meandmark.com/blog/2016/04/missing-required-module-swiftshims-problem/

Answer (score 0):

You can try delete derived data of your app and then clean and build app, you can follow the steps of the following link https://programmingwithswift.com/delete-derived-data-xcode/. Also, you can follow this link [Fixing Xcode](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Fixing-Xcode#:%7E:text=Reset%20to%20confirm.-,Delete%20Derived%20Data,there%20click%20the%20Delete%20button.)